# Is there any way to track android app usage from another app?

Tags: java, android, process, io

just wanted to know if it's possible to get app usage, like how many variables are declared, the values of them, memory address, would it be possible to do this from another app? (this would be an app developed by me), and if it is possible, how can I do it, hope you can help me, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Apps have limited, defined ways of interacting with each other, [see the API here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/), but asking for things like "how many variables are declared" is almost certainly not possible.